# "LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional" BUT I've know I'm passing a 2D argument

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-algebra, covariance

My first question, so grateful for feedback on how to better help you help me :)

On my Mac (Mojave, 10.14.6 with Python version 3.7.6.final.0), I'm getting the above error.
I've confirmed that my argument matrix has 2 dimensions (8 x 8).
I've worked through the Traceback, and used the relevant argument matrix in each of the subfunctions successfully, but not on the main function "monteCarlo".

BTW, this is code from Marcos López de Prado's "A ROBUST ESTIMATOR OF THE EFFICIENT FRONTIER"
I have made some modifications where the code was outdated (2.*) and some others to help assure myself that I am working with the matrix I expect.

Many, many thanks to the intrepid who care and dare to read through all this.

Below the error message is some of the code and results clipped from Jupyter Notebook.

---

```
> 
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-313-a5db76f0dc0a> in <module>
----> 1 monteCarlo(mu0=hist_ann_px_chg, cov0 = CovMatrix, nObs = NumObs, nSims=500, bWidth=.25, minVarPortf = False, shrink=False)
> 
<ipython-input-308-b7fbaf4dca14> in monteCarlo(mu0, cov0, nObs, nSims, bWidth, minVarPortf, shrink)
      5         mu1,cov1=simCovMu(mu0,cov0,nObs,shrink)
      6         if minVarPortf:mu1=None
----> 7         if bWidth>0:cov1=deNoiseCov(cov1,nObs*1./cov1.shape[1],bWidth)
      8         w1.loc[i]=optPort(cov1,mu1).values.flatten()
      9         w1_d.loc[i]=optPort_nco(cov1,mu1,int(cov1.shape[0]/2)).values.flatten()
> 
<ipython-input-306-062b76320e88> in deNoiseCov(cov0, q, bWidth)
     35 def deNoiseCov(cov0,q,bWidth):
     36     corr0=cov2corr(cov0)
---> 37     eVal0,eVec0=getPCA(corr0)
     38     eMax0,var0=findMaxEval(np.diag(eVal0),q,bWidth)
     39     nFacts0=eVal0.shape[0]-np.diag(eVal0)[::-1].searchsorted(eMax0)
> 
<ipython-input-306-062b76320e88> in getPCA(matrix)
     16 def getPCA(matrix):
     17 # Get eVal,eVec from a Hermitian matrix
---> 18     eVal,eVec=np.linalg.eigh(matrix)
     19     indices=eVal.argsort()[::-1] # arguments for sorting eVal desc
     20     eVal,eVec=eVal[indices],eVec[:,indices]
> 
<__array_function__ internals> in eigh(*args, **kwargs)
> 
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in eigh(a, UPLO)
   1432 
   1433     a, wrap = _makearray(a)
-> 1434     _assert_stacked_2d(a)
   1435     _assert_stacked_square(a)
   1436     t, result_t = _commonType(a)
> 
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in _assert_stacked_2d(*arrays)
    205         if a.ndim < 2:
    206             raise LinAlgError('%d-dimensional array given. Array must be '
--> 207                     'at least two-dimensional' % a.ndim)
    208 
    209 def _assert_stacked_square(*arrays):
> 
LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional
```

---

Below is the function that throws the error when I call with this statement:

```
monteCarlo(mu0=hist_ann_px_chg, cov0 = CovMatrix, nObs = NumObs, nSims=500, bWidth=.25, minVarPortf = False, shrink=False)
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
import yfinance as yf


yf.pdr_override() # <== that's all it takes :-)

# download dataframe
hist_data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("^GSPC ^VIX ^DJI ^IXIC ^FTSE ^GDAXI ^STOXX50E ^N225", start="2015-01-01", end="2020-01-1")
hist_data = hist_data.iloc[:,0:8]
hist_dly_px_chg = hist_data.pct_change()


NumObs = hist_dly_px_chg.shape[0]
CovMatrix = hist_dly_px_chg.cov()
print(type(CovMatrix)) # data.frame

CovMatrix = np.matrix(CovMatrix) # matrix (8 x 8)
print(type(CovMatrix))
print(CovMatrix.shape)
print(CovMatrix.ndim)
hist_ann_px_chg = hist_dly_px_chg.mean()
print(hist_ann_px_chg*NumObs)
```

---

When I make this function call:

```
print(np.linalg.eigh(CovMatrix))
```

I get the output I think I would expect, so I can't tell where the disconnect is:

---

```
(array([9.76607795e-07, 9.09734518e-06, 1.06092016e-05, 2.18149708e-05,
   7.30351257e-05, 1.16439127e-04, 2.39270121e-04, 7.82633431e-03]), matrix([[-4.82280240e-01, -4.58375572e-01, -5.31172874e-01,
      3.50650316e-02, -4.92673400e-01, -9.94286171e-02,
      1.25967021e-01,  7.37740277e-02],
    [-2.33051153e-02,  3.95717701e-02,  7.84798502e-02,
      8.95759250e-01,  1.02359842e-01, -1.47818043e-01,
      3.93700956e-01,  4.49340838e-02],
    [ 2.54965439e-02, -5.36050910e-01,  4.44240943e-01,
     -3.24298395e-01,  1.74936958e-01, -2.59428034e-01,
      5.54982822e-01,  5.97336351e-02],
    [ 8.28138825e-01, -8.35526265e-02, -1.54346913e-01,
      2.26457229e-02, -5.01976954e-01, -1.04165506e-01,
      1.19382708e-01,  7.60638006e-02],
    [-2.83219910e-01,  4.59584143e-01,  5.09453905e-01,
     -8.28536548e-02, -6.32657429e-01, -1.32770810e-01,
      1.28593449e-01,  8.79835438e-02],
    [ 1.06886068e-03, -7.82137852e-03,  1.94908915e-02,
     -2.38832357e-02, -9.03973958e-02,  9.05732488e-01,
      4.12218925e-01,  2.32359154e-02],
    [-1.33763053e-02,  5.31709637e-01, -4.80196149e-01,
     -2.88561906e-01,  2.10778168e-01, -2.24495845e-01,
      5.52334217e-01,  5.78853425e-02],
    [ 2.25154661e-03,  6.27599544e-04, -3.43348735e-03,
      6.49094855e-04, -1.06569389e-01, -4.16245867e-02,
      1.23854342e-01, -9.85673773e-01]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So who should I believe, you or the computer?

Let's look at the error.  At the lowest level `a` is the problem array.  Tracing up we see that it is the `corr0` array passed to `getPCA`: `getPCA(corr0)`

That is created by `corr0=cov2corr(cov0)`, where `cov0` is the `cov1` passed to `deNoiseCov(cov1,...)`

```
mu1,cov1=simCovMu(mu0,cov0,nObs,shrink)
```

I don't know what `cov2corr` and `simCovMu` do.  But since `deNoiseCov` appears to be your code, I assume you could put some diagnostic prints there, checking shape and dtype.

Since this code is coming from PY2, beware that a number of py2 list creators are generator like in py3.  `np.array(range(3))` still works, but many other cases will create scalar (0d) arrays (such as `map`).

Also the use of `np.matrix` is old; it's no longer very useful - but it still works (so probably isn't the cause of errors).

Comment: Thank you, hpaulj.  You helped me to trap the bug by pointing out that the matrix causing the problem wasn't the matrix I assured myself was correct.   I appreciated the other "heads ups" too -- but I wonder if you could unpack for me this part? "a number of py2 list creators are generator like in py3."  Many thanks again!  btw, I tried to upvote but I'm too new for it to count ;/

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I have to convert the sparse matrix to dense matrix.